# collect() showing timestamp as "datetime.datetime" while converting to row type

Tags: python, azure, dictionary, datetime, databricks

I have following dataframe as row type(converted to dataframe.collect()) to further processing but
it is converting as datetime.datetime(), how can i get rid of datetime.datetime and only display the timestamp.

[Row(unit_id='00001597', country='ITA', gateway_id='8988228', first_hb_info=Row(hb_time=datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 15, 12, 56, 19), battery=60, ctrl=4, service=24, rssi=11, power=1, op_mode='IDL'), last_hb_info=Row(hb_time=datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 2, 20, 18, 21), battery=100, ctrl=4, service=27, rssi=10, power=1, op_mode='\x00\x00\x00'), last_op_mode_hb_info=Row(hb_time=datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 2, 20, 10, 21), battery=100, ctrl=4, service=24, rssi=10, power=1, op_mode='IDL')]

Comment: What is your expecting output?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. The output should be in string format. like for e.g.[{'hb_time': '2022-03-15 12:56:19', 'battery': '60', 'ctrl': '4', 'service': '24', 'rssi': '11', 'power': '1', 'op_mode': 'IDL'}, {'hb_time': '2023-11-02 20:18:21', 'battery': '100', 'ctrl': '4', 'service': '27', 'rssi': '10', 'power': '1', 'op_mode': '\x00\x00\x00'}. I came to know to_json would do but i have nested struct element so looking how to handle that to_json with struct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `datetime.datetime` is because the field inside the nested column is of `TimestampType`.

You need to convert that to string and do collect.

Below is the code to convert it.

```
cols_to_alter = ['first_hb_info', 'last_hb_info', 'last_op_mode_hb_info']
struct_cols = ['hb_time', 'battery', 'ctrl', 'service', 'rssi', 'power', 'op_mode']

final_df = df_mod #your_current_dataframe.
for i in cols_to_alter:
    final_df = final_df.select('*',f'{i}.*').withColumn('hb_time',F.date_format('hb_time','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
    final_df = final_df.drop(i).select('*',F.struct(*struct_cols).alias(i)).drop(*struct_cols)
```

```
final_df.collect()
```

Output:

```
[Row(unit_id='00001597', country='ITA', gateway_id='8988228',
 first_hb_info=Row(hb_time='2022-03-15 10:30:00', battery=60, ctrl=4, service=24, rssi=11, power=1, op_mode='IDL'), 
 last_hb_info=Row(hb_time='2022-03-15 10:30:00', battery=60, ctrl=4, service=24, rssi=11, power=1, op_mode='IDL'), 
 last_op_mode_hb_info=Row(hb_time='2022-03-15 10:30:00', battery=60, ctrl=4, service=24, rssi=11, power=1, op_mode='IDL'))]
```

And if you want in json use below code.

```
final_df.toJSON().collect()
```

Output:

```
['{"unit_id":"00001597","country":"ITA","gateway_id":"8988228",
"first_hb_info":{"hb_time":"2022-03-15 10:30:00","battery":60,"ctrl":4,"service":24,"rssi":11,"power":1,"op_mode":"IDL"},
"last_hb_info":{"hb_time":"2022-03-15 10:30:00","battery":60,"ctrl":4,"service":24,"rssi":11,"power":1,"op_mode":"IDL"},
"last_op_mode_hb_info":{"hb_time":"2022-03-15 10:30:00","battery":60,"ctrl":4,"service":24,"rssi":11,"power":1,"op_mode":"IDL"}}']
```